# Como criar relacionameto de produtos com php e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

A algum tempo atrás fiz uma tentativa de relacionamento de produtos, mas não ficou funcional e creio que também não foi a forma mais correta, confesso, o mesmo é ruim, o que fiz foi basicamente isso:

Busco as linhas (Categorias) e logo abaixo onde estão os checks listo os produtos dessa categoria e seleciono o produto que desejo relacionar, isso pode ser visto nessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meus cheks estão configurados assim:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="produto[]" id="produto[]" value="<?php echo $row_produtos['id_produto']; ?>" /><?php echo $row_produtos['codigo']; ?>
```

Estou limitando a quantidade de 10 produtos, estou confuso e não consigo entender o que devo gravar em meu banco, o id_produto, id_categoria para posteriormente buscar e mostrar em minha página.

O que gostaria de saber é, como é a forma correta de desenvolver essa solução e 
no visual, como ficaria o cadastro?

Comment: Um produto pode ter N categorias é isso?

Comment: Olá @rray, isso mesmo.

Comment: Tive uma duvida semelhante, veja se isto resolve http://stackoverflow.com/q/23160254/1518921 (a ideia da pergunta é um produto com vários preços, deve lhe ajudar), claro que na época usei double por ser totalmente leigo, mas isto não tem haver com o problema hehehehe, basta ignorar, de resto talvez ler isto ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/3635, claro que se for para exibir o produto nem sempre vai precisar fazer o relacionamento

Comment: Você vai precisar de um tabela para produtos, categorias e uma chamada possívelmente `produto_categoria` que tem o `id` do produto e o `id`da categoria pelo menos.

Comment: Sim, @array, essas tabelas eu já tenho, inclusive com os nomes que você sitou.

Comment: A dúvida é na hora usar o PHP para gravar? o id do produto vem do form com vc pode pegar os ids das categorias e fazer um foreach para cadastrar na tabela de `produto_categoria`

Comment: Os ids das categorias creio, devem ficar nos meus checks, ai pego eles pelo foreach, minha dúvida crucial era o que gravar no banco.

Comment: Isso mesmo, o id do produto deve ser um input hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão:

Primeiro, se não me engano, você não deveria fazer um ID em HTML com array dessa forma: id="produto[]" (deixe apenas o nome)

Agora:
Na parte do banco de dados, bastaria criar uma tabela tabela intermediária para relacionar os produtos entre eles mesmos, ou sejá, você teria duas chaves estrangeiras nessa tabela apontando para a mesma chave primaria dos seus produtos.

Na parte visual.
Você poderia categorizar esse tipo de coisa na edição do próprio produto em si, e não na categoria dele.

Na tela do produto, você pode listar todos os outros produtos da mesma categoria e assim, você seleciona quais são relacionados.
Isso seria salvo com N (onde N pode ser até 10 pela sua regra) linhas nessa nova tabela onde a primeira chave é o produto em si, e a segunda chave é o produto relacionado.

Lembre-se apenas, de que você precisaria efetuar uma busca sempre nas duas chaves, uma vez que o produto em si pode estar na primeira e/ou na segunda.

Comment: Olá @Mario de M. Barros Neto, suas dicas foram importantíssimas para a solução do meu problema, agradeço.